# Truncating in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, truncate

I have this written:

```
<p><%= resource.description %></p>
```

However, I'd like to truncate so as to not allow any descriptions over X value. I tried:

```
<truncate (<%= resource.description %>, limit: 30)>
```

didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<p><%= truncate(resource.description, limit: 30) %></p>
```

Comment: In addition, here's the documentation for the method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate